# RxJs `sample` operator multiple times

Tags: typescript, rxjs, stream, observable, reactivex

In RxJS, when you need to combine two `Observable`s and emit only when **one** of those emits, you use `withLatestFrom`

```
source$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(other$),
  map(([sourceValue, otherValue]) => ...) // this is only executed when `source$` has new values, regardless of `other$` emission
)
```

If `source$` emits multiple times but `other$` don't, you always get the same, latest, value and **do** execute `map`.

If you don't need the value of the "signalling" stream, you can use `sample`.

```
interestingStream$.pipe(
  sample(signallingStream$),
  map((interestingValue) => ...) // this function does not receive `signallingStream$`'s values
)
```

However, `map` is only executed if `signallingStream$` emits *after* `interestingStream$` emitted a new value; no value is emitted twice downstream.

So my question is, is there an operator, a combination of operators, or something else that allows me to get multiple times the latest value of a source stream without forcing me to get and ignore the value of a signalling stream like in the following snippet?

```
signallingStream$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(interestingStream$),
  map(([_ignore_, interestingValue]) => interestingValue),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could use something like the following:

```
const shared$ = interestingStream$.pipe(
  publishReplay(1),
);

const source = signallingStream$.pipe(
  concatMapTo(shared$.pipe(take(1))),
);

shared$.connect();
```

`publishReplay()` should keep a single instance of `ReplaySubject()` so every time you subscribe to it it'll reemit the latest value from `interestingStream$` By calling `connect()` you make the Observable "hot".

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ewew2n